# C++ - Issue when using .at() method with string

Tags: c++

I have tried Googling and trying everything I can think of, but I can't overcome the problem. So I have come to the masters at StackOverflow!

I am having trouble using the .at() string method:

```
std::string letters = "QWERTYUIO";

// &(letters.at(0)) now evaluates to QWERTYUIO
// &(letters.at(5)) now evaluates to YUIO
// etc.
```

What I want is the nth character of the string, not a string starting at the nth character.

I tried the [] operator, but I now have a new problem. The code is currently (using the Allegro library, but I don't think that is affecting this):

```
std::string letters = "QWERTYUIO";
char letter;
char StringY[5];
int row = 0;

for(int l = 0; l <= 2; ++l){
    letter = letters[row + l];

    textout_ex(buffer, font, &letter, l * 30, 20, makecol(255, 255, 255), -1);

    sprintf(StringY, "%d", inventoryNum[row + l + 9]);
    textout_ex(buffer, font, StringY, l * 30, 20, makecol(255, 255, 255), -1);
}
```

What is happening is the letter variable seems to be appending the StringY of the previous iteration to itself for no apparent reason. This is driving me insane.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks,

Will.

Comment: @swegi Sorry, forgot to put that in my question! The value of row is 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`at()` returns a reference to the specified character in the string, so when you take its address with `&`, you get a pointer to that character (of type `char *`).

The problem is that you are then giving this pointer to something that expects a pointer to an *array of `char`s*. This also has the type `char *` so it type checks just fine, but it gets treated as a character array rather than a single character.

You probably want to just drop the `&` and use `letters.at(5)`.

---

Some people suggested using `operator[]` instead. It would still cause the same issue if you wrote `&(letters[5])`. The difference between `at()` and `operator[]` is that the former does bounds checking while the latter does not.

Comment: @hammar What a fantastic answer. Thank for your help! The only problem is that the Allegro function 'textout_ex' expects a 'const char*' parameter, so it fires up an error message when attempting to put 'letters.at(row + l)' in. Many thanks, though!

Comment: @Will: In that case, you simply need to convert your single character to a string containing a single character. One way of doing this is `char foo[2] = { letters.at(5), '\0' };` and then just give `foo` to `textout_ex`.

Comment: @hammar It worked! Thanks for all your help, I am eternally grateful!

Answer (score 3):

see [string::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)

use it just as:

```
(letters.at(0));
(letters.at(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator[]`.

```
char c = letters[5];
```

Edit: Your problem *is* the Allegro library. It's decades old and written in C. You really need something from the current century. For example, with your `sprintf`, then I sure hope it doesn't need more than 5 characters, and you never wrote a 0 terminator or anything like that.

You should move to something more modern, like Direct3D itself. D3DX has a Font class that can render text transparently without the user having to manually write it to a texture, and you can use your own C++ string handling instead of the disgusting handling in the code posted. This is at least a small improvement:

```
std::string letters = "QWERTYUIO";
std::stringstream strstream;    
for(int l = 0, row = 0; l <= 2; ++l){
    char letter;
    letter = letters[row + l];

    textout_ex(buffer, font, &letter, l * 30, 20, makecol(255, 255, 255), -1);

    strstream << inventoryNum[row + l + 9];
    textout_ex(buffer, font, strstream.str().c_str(), l * 30, 20, makecol(255, 255, 255), -1);
    strstream.clear();
}
```

Comment: This has caused a new problem, which I have edited into the initial question. Thanks very much for your quick response, and any further help is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just say `letters[5]`, or whatever position you need.

Comment: This has caused a new problem, which I have edited into the initial question. Thanks very much for your quick response, and any further help is also appreciated.

Comment: @Will: You're using `textout_ex`, whose third argument has to be a *pointer to a null-terminated char array*. But `letters[5]` is just a single `char`! You could say something like `char letter[2] = { letters[5], '\0' };`, or be fancy and use `substr` as in `letters.substr(5, 1).c_str()`.